# Setting session in the frontend not accesible in the Observer

Tags: session

Here is how i setup session:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
    $mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
    require_once $mageFilename;
    $app = Mage::app('default'); 
    Mage::app();

    Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));

    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    $customer_id = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getId();



    $GrandTotal = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadByCustomer($customer_id)->getGrandTotal();
    $HalfTotal = $GrandTotal / 2;


    $PcPay = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getPcPayment();
    $result = array();
    if($PcPay != "") {
    $result['GrandTotal'][] = $GrandTotal;
    } else {
        $result['GrandTotal'][] = $HalfTotal;
    }
    echo json_encode($result);
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setPcPayment('pc_payment');
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->unsPayOnDel();
    ?>
```

Then in the observer when i try:

```
$PcPay = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getPcPayment();
Mage::log("PCPAYMENT - $PcPay");
```

After that in the system log it seems the session is not set. It seems it's empty.

Why i can not use the frontend session to the observer, is it possible and how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your observer code with this:

```
$PcPay = Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name"=>"frontend"))->getPcPayment();
Mage::log("PCPAYMENT - $PcPay");
```